# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'client' while importing values created in one file to another

Tags: python-2.7

I have created a common Python file with a `RTUIP` function which I need to use in another file.

File 1:

```
def RTUIP():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        IPComPort = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        IPComPort = raw_input('Enter Com Port for RTU or IP Address for TCP: ')

    if len(IPComPort) > 3:
        client = ModbusTcpClient(IPComPort, timeout=10, delay=5)
    else:
        client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', timeout=.5)
        client.baudrate = 115200
        client.port = int(IPComPort) - 1  
        client.connect()
```

File 2: Here I am importing the `RTUIP` function from `File 1` and trying to use the method:

```
from Common import RTUIP
    RTUIP()
    Regs = client.read_holding_registers(MeterAdd, 39, unit=1)
```

I get this error:

```
client keyword: Undefined Variable Client
```

When I change it to:

```
 a = RTUIP()
    Regs = a.client.read_holding_registers(MeterAdd, 39, unit=1)
```

`client` keyword does not throw any error, but when I run the code I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'client'
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Your function does not return anything (which is NoneType actually so the variable a is NoneType), don't expect from NoneType.client to work.

Comment: how to resolve it?

Comment: Add `return client` inside your function (at the last line of your function)

Comment: Added. Still throwing same error

Comment: So change `Regs = a.read_holding_registers(MeterAdd, 39, unit=1) ` as a holds client now.

Comment: It worked. Thank You.

Comment: Good luck, glad I helped :)